# clang not recognize GUARDED_BY

Tags: c++, clang, thread-safety

clang version

```
Debian clang version 11.0.1-2
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

my code here：

```
std::mutex m_;
int s GUARDED_BY(m_);   


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    s = 0;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compile command：clang -c -Wthread-safety -std=c++14 main.cpp
compile error：

```
main.cpp:67:6: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
int s GUARDED_BY(m_);
     ^
     ;
1 error generated.
```

is my clang version too low?

Comment: Have you [defined](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html) `GUARDED_BY`? please show a [mre]

Comment: I think this is the feature: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html, but I can't see if it requires clang 15 or if it exists in earlier versions too.

Comment: @Frodyne it was in [clang 3.5.0](https://releases.llvm.org/3.5.0/tools/clang/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html)

Comment: You need to define those macros, as in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html#mutexheader . Or directly use the attribute syntax.

Comment: @MarcGlisse 3ks for your answer, problem is solved after i add the macros

Comment: @AlanBirtles 3ks for u too

Comment: @Frodyne 3ks for u too